# Using PHP and JS, why do I get an error returned from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, json

'gday.

I am trying to code a file upload without the need for a page refresh using PHP, js and CSS.

When I run the code and view the response in Console tab of web developer tools in FF the code is 200 - OK, for the post but the returned json value is seen as an error.

Is the move_uploaded_file directive in the following code being used correctly and if it is what other reason is there for the code failing?

I have tried researching similar questions on SO and other sites but cannot pinpoint my error. I am able to browse directly to the file path and it has the correct permissions, in fact since this is on a localhost dev machine, I have given all users full permissions to the folder but it still fails.

Any insight appreciated.

The relevant code snippets follow:
HTML input:

```
<form>      
    <div class="span3" id="drop">
        <p> Click to upload image.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="PhotoUpload" id="PhotoUpload" />
</form>
```

.js:

```
$(function(){
    //trigger file input when the box is clicked
    $("#drop").click(function(){
        $("#PhotoUpload").click();
    });

    //stop browsers from opening the file when its moved
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //Handle the file upload on select file
    $('input[type=file]').on('change',  fileUpload);
});

function fileUpload(event){
        //give the user some info
    $("#drop").html(event.target.value+" uploading...");

    //get the selected file
    files = event.target.files;

    //check what data   
    var data = new FormData();                                   

    //get the data as an array
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if(!file.type.match('image.*')) {              
            //check file type
            $("#drop").html("Please choose a file of type image");
        }else if(file.size > 1048576){
            //check file size (in bytes)
            $("#drop").html("Sorry, maximum upload size is 1mb.");
        }else{
            //append the uploadable file to FormData object
            data.append("file", file, file.name);

            //create a new XMLHttpRequest
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     

            //post file data for upload
            xhr.open("POST", '../includes/custom/upload.php', true);  
            xhr.send(data);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                //get response and show the uploading status
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if(xhr.status === 200 && response.status == 'ok'){
                    $("#drop").html("Your file uploaded successfully. Click to upload another.");
                }else if(response.status == 'type_err'){
                    $("#drop").html("Please choose an image file. Click to retry..");
                }else{
                    $("#drop").html("An error occured, please try again.");
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST) == true){
    //create tmp file name
    $fileName = time().'_'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    //set the upload path
    $targetDir = "../includes/custom/upload/";
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName;

    //allow only these file formats
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','JPG','PNG');

    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        //move the file to server
        // ----- it appears that this is where the code breaks ----- //
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            $response['status'] = 'ok';
        }else{
            $response['status'] = 'err';
        }
    }else{
        $response['status'] = 'type_err';
    }

    //respond json
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

CSS provided for complete clarity:

```
/* the file upload styling */
#drop{
    border: 3px dashed #0087F7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #F4F4F5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#drop{
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 54px 54px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#drop p{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#PhotoUpload{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: maybe change `$_FILES["file"]` to `$_FILES["file"][0]`?

Comment: Thanks, Manuel Otto. Good suggestion. I tried it but unfortunately it has not solved the issue. The result with this change is that the PHP now defaults to the catchall error handler of type_err whereas it was being caught at err prior to the change.

Comment: Ok, was only an idea. Can you confirm the `$targetFilePath` is right? maybe append it to the status.

Comment: Thanks, have checked that and used fqdn as full file path to double check but behaviour is still the same. I think the next step is to remove the function logic from the .js code and put it in the PHP section to see if I get different behaviour.

Comment: One more thing to try is to call `file_put_contents('../includes/custom/upload/test.txt','test');` from a seperate test.php...

Comment: No different behaviour I'm afraid but your comment has pushed my thoughts into a different direction. This code is hanging off a Joomla framework and I suspect the issue may be due to url rewriting for sef set in the global parameters of the site. I will test my theory in the morning. Thanks for your input. Appreciated.

Comment: Let's give some attention to this abandoned page (abandoned questions are bad for StackOverflow because they represent a knowledge deadend for researchers).  Can you tell me why you think `move_` is the point of failure?  Have you printed some checkpoints to screen?  Are there any errors in the error log?  Can you echo to verify that your process is passing the `in_array()` check?  Can you `var_export($_FILES["file"]);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and give me some feedback -- it is completely untested:

```
$uploads_dir = '../includes/custom/uploads/';
foreach ($_FILES['PhotoUpload']['error'] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['PhotoUpload']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $fileName = time().'_'.basename($_FILES['PhotoUpload']['name'][$key]); // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        if (preg_match('~^[\w.-]{1,240}\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g)$~i',$fileName)) {  // file validation
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$fileName")) {
                $response['status']='ok';
            } else {
                $response['status']='move_uploaded() failed: '.error_get_last();
            }
        }else{
            $response['status']='invalid generated filename';
        }
    }else{
        $response['status']='$_FILES upload error';
    }
}
```

I've baked in some checkpoints, validations, and security processes which are a blend of the commented knowledge under the [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) manual pages.

Comment: @redant Please use this to try to pinpoint where the failure begins.  (I would consider this a miracle if it worked right out of the box.)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. This was a project which was partly canned so I never really followed up but you are right, abandoned pages are not good for SO. I'll dig up the old code in the next day or two, revisit it and post back here.